# C - realloc error: corrupted size vs prev_size

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, realloc

Could someone please explain the error?
I was getting the error until, on a whim, I changed the line from:

```
char *tmp = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*length);
// to                                           added 1
char *tmp = realloc(str, sizeof(char) * length + 1);
```

I thought that multiplying `sizeof(char)` by length would reallocate a new memory area of `size=sizeof(char)*length`. I'm not understanding why adding 1 fixes the problem.

```
    void edit_print(char *inputStr, size_t space_size) {
      size_t ch_position = 0;
      size_t space_column_count = 0;
      size_t num_spaces_left = 0;
      while ((inputStr[ch_position] != '\0')) {
        if ((inputStr[ch_position] == '\t') && (space_size !=0)) {
          num_spaces_left = (space_size-(space_column_count % space_size));
          if (ch_position == 0 || !(num_spaces_left)) {
            for (size_t i=1; i <= space_size; i++) {
              putchar(' ');
              space_column_count++;
            }
            ch_position++;
          } else {
            for (size_t i=1; i <= num_spaces_left; i++) {
              putchar(' ');
              space_column_count++;
            }
            ch_position++;
          }
        } else {
          putchar(inputStr[ch_position++]);
          space_column_count++;
        }
      }
      printf("\n");
    }

        int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
          size_t space_size_arg = 3; 
          int inputch;
          size_t length = 0;
          size_t size = 10;
          char *str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char) * size);
          printf("Enter stuff\n");

          while ((inputch = getchar()) != EOF) {
            if (inputch == '\n') {
              str[length++] = '\0';

              //changed line below
              char *tmp = realloc(str, sizeof(char) * length + 1);

              if (tmp == NULL) {
                exit(0);
              } else {
                str = tmp;
              }
              edit_print(str, space_size_arg);
              length = 0;
            } else {
              str[length++] = inputch;
              if (length == size) {
                char *tmp = realloc(str, sizeof(char) * (size += 20));
                if (tmp == NULL) {
                  exit(0);
                } else {
                  str = tmp;
                }
              }
            }
          }
          free(str);
          return 0;
        }
```

EDIT: the error message I original got was the one in the heading of this post. After making the changes suggested by chux, the error is "realloc(): invalid next size: *hexnumber**"

Comment: Recommend letting us in on "the error" Could be very helpful in figuring out what went wrong.

Comment: My guess: `edit_print` contains a buffer overrun error. You masked this bug by giving it some extra room to overrun into.

Comment: OT: This does not explain the error, yet `sizeof(char) * length + 1` is semantically incorrect.  The `sizeof() ` should multiple by the sum of `length + 1`.  But since, in this case, `sizeof(char)==1` --> no problem.

Comment: First of all, "sizeof(char)" is defined to be 1, so is irrelevant and superfluous everywhere. Then, the only code that seems to do anything with all this memory you're allocating is edit_print(), which you're not showing us.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I added the function

Comment: @user4581301 the error is in the header. Thats all im getting.

Comment: @rhoward207 Prior to each `... = realloc(ptr, sz);`, add `fprintf(stderr, "%d %p %zu\n", __LINE__, (void*)ptr, sz);` and report the last output before code dies.

Comment: @chux what is sz in the arguments?

Comment: In `realloc(NULL, sizeof(char) * size);`, `sz` is `sizeof(char) * size`,  In `realloc(str, sizeof(char) * length + 1);`, `sz` is `sizeof(char) * length + 1`.  In `realloc(str, sizeof(char) * (size += 20));` `sz` is `sizeof(char) * (size + 20));`  (not `+=`).

Comment: General comment: A weak design attribute is testing the size _after_ setting an element of the array.  A better approach would test space availability first before `str[length++] = inputch;` and before `str[length++] = '\0';`

Comment: Minor: `if ((!*end) && num > 0)` ---> `if (options[2] != end && (!*end) && num > 0)`

Comment: Instead of including `process_options()` code.  A [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would have used `size_t space_size_arg = 3;` - assuming that still fails.  GTG

Comment: arent you allocated the buffer `str` for the next string on each loop. Are they all the same size? First time you have str = 10 bytes, then you count chars and realloc str to the size you just read. But that buffer is used fro the next string

Answer (score 2):

`size` needs updating when `inputch == '\n'`.

`char *tmp = realloc(str, sizeof(char) * length + 1 /* or no +1 */);` can shrink the allocation.  which makes a later `if (length == size)` invalid (the true allocation size is smaller) and so `str[length++] = inputch;` lost memory access protection.  Update `size` to fix that hole.

`+1` not needed - it simply hid the problem as the `+ 1` did not shrink the allocation as much.

```
  char *tmp = realloc(str, sizeof(char) * length);
  if (tmp == NULL) {
    exit(0);
  } else {
    str = tmp;
  }
  size = length; // add
```

---

Concerning `sizeof(char)*` code.  The idea of scaling by the size of the target type is good, yet with `char` it is not important as it is *always* 1.  [@Lee Daniel Crocker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177778/c-realloc-error-corrupted-size-vs-prev-size/48177963#comment83336040_48177778)

If code wants to reflect that the type of the target may change, do not use `size(the_type)`, use `sizeof(*the_pointer)`.  Easier to code, review and maintain.

```
// Don't even need to code the type `str` points to
tmp = realloc(str, sizeof *str * length);
```

Comment: unfortunately your suggestion does not fix the error. I will edit my post to include what I am seeing. I also added edit_print. thank for the info about sizeof(type).

Comment: Please provide a [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for further help.

Comment: @chux after adding fprintf, last few lines: #####  ####### ####### ######               # ####### ######
100 0x55da9f4416a0 41
#     # #     # #     # #     #              # #     # #     #
100 0x55da9f4416a0 41
#       #     # #     # #     #              # #     # #     #
100 0x55da9f4416a0 44
*** Error in `./project1': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x000055da9f4416c0 ***
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: fprintf(stderr, "%d %p %zu\n", __LINE__, (void*)str, sizeof(char)*length+1); @chux

Comment: @rhoward207 Notice that the problem occurs on the first non-blank line shorter than prior ones.    Certainly the issue is in shrinking the allocation.  The 100 is suspicious as no line is longer than about 75 characters - hmmmm.