# getting a "corrupted size vs. prev_size" error in c

Tags: c, linux

I need to make a function to receive an unlimited input, that will only stop reading when reaching and EOF. I have to use the `realloc` function.

This is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getInput() {
    char *currentString, currentChar;
    int currentSize;
    currentString = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
    currentSize = 0;
    currentChar = 0;
    if (currentString != NULL) {
        while (currentChar != EOF) {
            currentChar = getchar();
            currentString[currentSize++] = currentChar;
            currentString = realloc(currentString, currentSize);
        }
    }
    return currentString;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *userInput;

    userInput = getInput();
    printf("\n string is: %s", userInput);
    return 0;
}
```

The code works just as it should, except for whenever I input a string of a size of more then around 13 characters, I get the following error (the filename is list_ab):

```
*** Error in `./list_ab': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x08ff6010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x67377)[0xb75a7377]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6d2f7)[0xb75ad2f7]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7049e)[0xb75b049e]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(realloc+0x10e)[0xb75b162e]
./list_ab[0x804851d]
./list_ab[0x8048544]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf7)[0xb7558637]
./list_ab[0x80483d1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 359220     /home/user/Desktop/Maman12/list_ab
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 08:02 359220     /home/user/Desktop/Maman12/list_ab
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:02 359220     /home/user/Desktop/Maman12/list_ab
08ff6000-09017000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7400000-b7421000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7421000-b7500000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b750d000-b7529000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 931606     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7529000-b752a000 rw-p 0001b000 08:02 931606     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7540000-b76f0000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 933356     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b76f0000-b76f2000 r--p 001af000 08:02 933356     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b76f2000-b76f3000 rw-p 001b1000 08:02 933356     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b76f3000-b76f6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b770b000-b770e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b770e000-b7710000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0          [vvar]
b7710000-b7711000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7711000-b7733000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 931813     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
b7733000-b7734000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7734000-b7735000 r--p 00022000 08:02 931813     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
b7735000-b7736000 rw-p 00023000 08:02 931813     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
bfd35000-bfd56000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

After a-lot of googling, I found out that the error happens whenever I try to write to an inaccessible location, but none of the fixes mentioned worked.
How can I solve this issue?
If it helps in running on linux vm.

Comment: 1. `input a large string`, how large are we talking about. 2. We need to check return value of `realloc()`. 3.. `getchar()` returns `int` to cover `-1`(EOF) usually, but `currentChar` is a `char`. 4. You're not terminating the string.

Comment: large means like 13 chars or more, i'll mention it

Comment: Would by any chance ```currentString = realloc(currentString, currentSize + 1);``` work?

Comment: it works omg no way

Comment: @PlainXYZ yea but I don't think it actually fixes the problem. Check this one out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177778/c-realloc-error-corrupted-size-vs-prev-size

Comment: I don't know, it does currently work.
I will do some more QA later probably though.

Comment: One problem is that you treat user input as a string. But it may not be a string.

Comment: @PlainXYZ Also check this one out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53905164/realloc-inside-a-function-corrupted-size-vs-prev-size It may help you to track down the actual problem

Comment: `printf("\n string is: %s",userInput);` is bad as `userInput` does not point to a _string_ (no `'\0'`).

Comment: @Cheatah this would be irrelevant as OP is providing the input anyways

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yea this might be a problem

Comment: At least 4 problems: not enough space, wrong type for `currentChar`, missing appended 0, no `free()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- the type of `currentChar` should be `int` to accommodate all possible values returned by `getchar()`, namely all values of type `unsigned char` (`0` to `255` for 8-bit bytes) and the special negative value `EOF` (usually defined as `(-1)`).
- the first time you test `currentChar != EOF`, the variable `currentChar` is uninitialized, causing undefined behavior.
- you should test for `EOF` after reading the byte from standard input and before appending it to the array.
- you reallocate the array **after** setting the next character: except for the first time, you write the byte beyond the end of the allocated object: you should reallocate the array **before** appending the byte.
- you do not allocate enough space for the null terminator, and you do not set it.
- you do not check for `malloc()` nor `realloc()` failure.
- you do not free the string in `main()`.
- reallocating one byte at a time is inefficient.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getInput(void) {
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t size = 8;
    char *str = malloc(size);
    char *newstr;
    int c;

    if (str == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failure for %zu bytes\n", size);
        return NULL;
    }
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (len + 2 > size) {
            /* increase the allocated block size by 50% */
            size += size / 2;
            newstr = realloc(str, size);
            if (newstr == NULL) {
                free(str);
                fprintf(stderr, "realloc failure for %zu bytes\n", size);
                return NULL;
            }
            str = newstr;
        }
        str[len++] = c;
    }
    /* try and reduce the size of the allocated string */
    newstr = realloc(str, len + 1);
    if (newstr != NULL)
        str = newstr;
    /* set the null terminator */
    str[len] = '\0';
    return str;
}

int main() {
    char *userInput = getInput();
    if (userInput) {
        printf("string is: %s\n", userInput);
        free(userInput);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To summarise all the inputs from comments:

1. `argc` & `argv` are not used, then why declare them?
2. `getchar()` returns a `int` to cover `EOF` which is usually all bits set to `1` becomes `-1` in 2's complement notation. So, `currentChar` needs to be `int`.
3. String is not null terminated, may cause buffer overrun when used as a nul-terminated string.
4. `free()` the allocated memory after usage.
5. Make space for `nul`('\0') in `str`  & Check the return value of `realloc()`.
6. Don't be generous with variable names, reading will take time.

Code simplified:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* getInput() {
    char *str = malloc (sizeof (char) * 2);
    if (!str) {
        perror ("malloc"); return NULL;
    }
    int ich;
    int slen = 0;
    while ((ich = getchar()) != EOF) {
        str[slen++] = ich;
        char* str2 = realloc (str, slen + 1);
        if (!str2) {
            perror ("realloc"); free (str); return NULL;
        }
        str = str2;
    }
    str[slen] = '\0';
    return str;
}

int main() {
    char *userInput = getInput();
    if (userInput) {
        printf ("String is: %s\n", userInput);
        free (userInput);
    }
    return 0;
}
```